# Writing `render*()` and `*Output()` functions for UI output in R for shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am the author of the [equatiomatic](https://github.com/datalorax/equatiomatic) R package. I would like to write and export `renderEq()` and `eqOutput()` functions to make it easier to use with Shiny. Unfortunately, I can't figure it out. The below works for a basic shiny app.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(equatiomatic)
library(gtsummary)
library(gt)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("equatiomatic w/Shiny"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      multiInput(
        inputId = "xvars", label = "Select predictor variables :",
        choices = names(mpg)[-8],
        selected = "displ"
      )
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("eq"),
      gt_output("tbl")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  model <- reactive({
    form <- paste("hwy ~ ", paste(input$xvars, collapse = " + "))
    lm(as.formula(form), mpg)
  })
  
  output$eq <- renderUI(
    withMathJax(
      helpText(
        equatiomatic:::format.equation(
          extract_eq(model(), wrap = TRUE, terms_per_line = 3)
        )
      )
    )
  )
  
  output$tbl <- render_gt({
    as_gt(tbl_regression(model()))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'd really like to simplify this so the Ui part is just `eqOutput("eq")` and the server part is something like

```r
output$eq <- renderEq(
  extract_eq(model(), wrap = TRUE, terms_per_line = 3)
)
```

I know of `htmlwidgets::shinyWidgetOutput()` but that doesn't seem to help in this case because I'm trying to modify a UI element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cross posted this [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/writing-render-and-output-functions-for-ui-output/112063/3) and got an answer, so I'm posting it here too in case it helps others. The solution is to use the `installExprFunction()` and `createRenderFunction()` functions from shiny. These can then be wrapped in its own render function, as follows.

```r
renderEq <- function(expr, env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE, outputArgs = list()) {
  shiny::installExprFunction(expr = expr, name = "func", eval.env = env, quoted = quoted)
  shiny::createRenderFunction(func = func, function(value, session, name, ...) {
    as.character(withMathJax(helpText(equatiomatic:::format.equation(x = value))))
  }, eqOutput, outputArgs)
}
```

And for `eqOutput()` it's just

```r
eqOutput <- function(outputId) {
  shiny::htmlOutput(outputId = outputId)
}
```

So the full example, ensuring that it renders properly both ways, is

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(equatiomatic)
library(gtsummary)
library(gt)

renderEq <- function(expr, env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE, outputArgs = list()) {
  shiny::installExprFunction(expr = expr, name = "func", eval.env = env, quoted = quoted)
  shiny::createRenderFunction(func = func, function(value, session, name, ...) {
    as.character(withMathJax(helpText(equatiomatic:::format.equation(x = value))))
  }, eqOutput, outputArgs)
}

eqOutput <- function(outputId) {
  shiny::htmlOutput(outputId = outputId)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("equatiomatic w/Shiny"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      multiInput(
        inputId = "xvars", label = "Select predictor variables :",
        choices = names(mpg)[-8],
        selected = "displ"
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      eqOutput("eq_new"),
      uiOutput("eq"),
      gt_output("tbl")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  model <- reactive({
    form <- paste("hwy ~ ", paste(input$xvars, collapse = " + "))
    lm(as.formula(form), mpg)
  })
  
  output$eq_new <- renderEq(expr = extract_eq(model(), wrap = TRUE, terms_per_line = 3))
  output$eq <- renderUI(
    withMathJax(
      helpText(
        equatiomatic:::format.equation(
          extract_eq(model(), wrap = TRUE, terms_per_line = 3)
        )
      )
    )
  )
  
  output$tbl <- render_gt({
    as_gt(tbl_regression(model()))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: One other minor note, you do still have to have `withMathJax()` somewhere or these functions end up just spitting back the text version of the equation.